# SLF4J ClassNotFoundException in WildFly 15

Tags: java, wildfly, slf4j

A JEE application that was working fine on WildFly 8 was updated to WildFly 15. The application works fine and log messages are written, but from time to time, this exception happens:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYEJB0054: Failed to marshal EJB parameters
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:592)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:172)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:938)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:177)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:112)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5354.importInfo(Unknown Source)
    at xx.xxxx.xxx.boundary.SampleClass.start(SampleClass.java:187)
    at xx.xxxx.xxx.boundary.SampleClass.start(SampleClass.java:158)
    at xx.xxxx.xxx..boundary.SampleClass$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.start(Unknown Source)
    at xx.xxxx.xxx.agents.SampleAgent.importFromFolders(SampleAgent.java:105)
    at xx.xxxx.xxx.agents.SampleAgent.execute(SampleAgent.java:74)
    at xx.xxxx.xxx.AbstractAgent.run(AbstractAgent.java:34)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger from [Module "application-name.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.ClassLoaderClassCloner.clone(ClassLoaderClassCloner.java:51)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:158)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:130)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:179)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.cloner.SerializingCloner.clone(SerializingCloner.java:130)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.clone(LocalEjbReceiver.java:378)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.clone(LocalEjbReceiver.java:360)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:122)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:479)
    at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocation(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:491)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:491)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocation(DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:491)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocation(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:491)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:165)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:491)
    at org.wildfly.common.context.Contextual.runExConsumer(Contextual.java:203)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequestInitial(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:327)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:173)
    ... 15 more
```

Initially the WAR file included SLF4J API 1.7.5. I've tried with 1.7.22 that is the one provided by WildFly 15, but the issue still happens. I also tried setting the dependency as 'provided' and including a jboss-dependency-structure dependency to SLF4J without success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.slf4j" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

After setting the dependency as 'provided', I've checked in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the WAR file and no SLF4J lib is provided there, so I assume it should be using the one provided by WildFly.

But the most strange thing is that this error happens in some points, but not in others. Log files are being written. Even the error message of ClassNotFound is being written in the log files.

I've also uncompressed all the jar files inside WEB-INF/lib to be sure no dependency is including any SLF4J implementation. Then I searched for *slf4j* in all the folders. I get some matches inside Flyway and Freemarker, but they are no implementation, so I think they should not be a problem.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: That looks odd for sure. Is there by chance an slf4j binding in your deployment? The binding should be added by default to all deployments assuming the logging subsystem defaults.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I've updated the question. I've searched in all the contained libraries, and nothing relevant was found... do you think those classes from Flyway or Freemarker could be a problem? there were present in the previous version of the application when there was no issue.

Comment: That could be possible. I'm assuming this is a remote EJB. Do you use any other logging frameworks like log4j by chance? I'm just wondering if we could try a workaround.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I've tried including the dependency log4j-slf4j-impl in my WAR file, but like that the deployment into WildFly fails (IllegalArgumentException). I've tried disabling provided logging as explained here https://gist.github.com/vdevigere/44073b102f0bc93e0759 but same issue happens. Is that the way to switch to Log4j?

Comment: That was going to be my suggested workaround was to exclude the server from adding dependencies. If that didn't work I'm not sure what the issue could be. Is there anyway you could create a reproducer? I'm not sure where to start looking. Also feel free to move this over to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wildfly for more of a conversation.